# changing between more than one script for one textview in android

Tags: android, string, textview, android-activity

I'm working on an android application with 2 activities.

The first activity contains 2 buttons ( `btn1` , `btn2`). The second activity conatains `textview` and a back button. In the `string.xml` I have to strings ( `str1`, `str2`).

What I want is when I click on `btn1` the second activity should open and the `textview` will show the first string `str1` and when I click on the second button `btn2` the second activity open and the same `textview` show the second string `str2`

Comment: When starting an activity you can add the string content as an extra in the intent

Answer (score 1):

when you are starting the activity you are sending an intent like this

```
startActivity(intent);
```

In this intent pass a parameter using `putExtra`. in the parameter put an identifier of the buttons.

From the second activity get the extra data usibg `getExtra`. From there check the identifiers and show related stringo

I hope you know how to use `putExtra` and `getExtra`. If not google them

For more details check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Comment: Thank you but I really dont understand what to do
Will you please type the command that I should use

Comment: please go to the link I posted in the answer... and read the articles thoroughly